# how can make synchronous promise in angular2

Tags: http, angular, promise, synchronous

I am trying to call a function located in service class,and if that function returns data,one boolean variable sets true. I have 2 class as bollow:student.ts and service.ts:

// student.ts

```
    public ngOnInit() {
      this.config.load().then(() => {

      this.service.getRecords().then(
         function () { console.log("success getRecord");
                       this.loading = false; },
         function () { console.log("failed getRecord"); 
                       this.loading = true; });

    });
  }
```

//service.ts

```
 public getRecord(id: number): Promise<T> {
            return this.getRecordImpl();

        }

 private getRecordsImpl(): Promise<T[]> {




        let url = this.serviceUrl;

        return this.http.get(url, this.getRequestOptionsWithToken())
            .toPromise()
            .then(res => {
                this.records = this.extractData<T[]>(res);
                for (var i = 0; i < this.records.length; i++) {
                    var record = this.records[i];
                    this.onRecord(record);

                }

                 return this.records;

            })

            .catch(this.handleError);

    }
```

by the now, records from service returns, but this.service.getRecords(); is undefined. and I can't use

> .then

for handling succeed and failure actions. 
I know that it is not good idea to make it synchronous. but think that being Asynchronous causes getRecords becomes undefined. What is the solution for handling that. I want it runs sequentially. and if service returns any records , variable initialize to false, otherwise it sets to true.

Many thanks for any help and guide.

Comment: What do you mean by `this.service.getRecords();` is `undefined`? Does it mean the return value of `getRecords()` is `undefined` (unlikely) or that `this.service` is undefined? Where does `this.service` come from? (where is it set?)

Comment: getRecords is a function in my service.ts which returns list of students. By the now it works and when I call it, list of students returns. but I want to change an attribute value when getRecords execute successfully, for that purpose I added this.service.getRecords().then (function () { console.log("success getRecord"); this.loading = false; }, function () { console.log("failed getRecord"); this.loading = true; }); but I got an error for using .then in an undefined object.

Comment: I am looking for a way to do something when the service returns data. when I call this.service.getRecords() , records are returned, but my question is how can I do something after returning records from service?

Comment: The code looks fine to me. No idea why it doesn't work.

Comment: I think because of being asynchronous of ajax ,following code in student.ts : this.service.getRecords().then(
         function () { console.log("success getRecord");
                       this.loading = false; },
         function () { console.log("failed getRecord"); 
                       this.loading = true; });

    }); calles first and after that function getRecords in the service calls. I am not sure, but I think maybe something like $q in angular1 can help. Am I right?

Comment: I don't know Angular1 but it sounds unlikely. This is a very simple use case and should just work. Might be something subtle that I can't see by just looking at your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think your aproach is not correct, what is the point to make a promise synchronous ? If you really really want to do this I suggest you to dig in the [`Synchronous programming with es6 generators`](https://eladnava.com/write-synchronous-node-js-code-with-es6-generators/) but usually the job is done much smother.

From your code I see that you are consuming your Promise by attaching .then() in the service. In this way you should create a new Promise.

```
private getRecordsImpl(): Promise<T[]> {
let url = this.serviceUrl;
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  this.http.get(url, this.getRequestOptionsWithToken())
    .toPromise()
    .then(res => {
      this.records = this.extractData<T[]>(res);
      for (var i = 0; i < this.records.length; i++) {
        var record = this.records[i];
        this.onRecord(record);

      }
      resolve(this.records);
    })
    .catch(this.handleError);
 })
}
```

And in your code use:

```
  this.service.getRecords().then(
     function (records) { console.log("success getRecord");
                   this.loading = false; },
     function (err) { console.log("failed getRecord"); 
                   this.loading = true; });
```